# xuggle and live broadcasting rtmp

Tags: java, rtmp, live-streaming, xuggle

I found an example of a live broadcast rtmp using xuggle, but I can not run it as xuggle distributions do not include libx264-normal.ffpreset, which is proposed to take from the distribution.
Perhaps an example only applies to older versions of xuggle, if so, is there any examples of a live broadcast using the latest version xuggle?

```
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Configuration;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainerFormat;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPixelFormat;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IRational;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.video.ConverterFactory;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.video.IConverter;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class XugglerRtmpReferenceImpl {
    private static String url = "";
    private static String fileName = "/home/pavel/test.flv";
    private static int framesToEncode = 60;
    //screen capture size/pos 
    private static int x = 0;
    private static int y = 0;
    private static int height = 480;
    private static int width = 640;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IContainer container = IContainer.make();
        IContainerFormat containerFormat_live =
                IContainerFormat.make();
        containerFormat_live.setOutputFormat("flv", url + fileName,
                null);
        container.setInputBufferLength(0);
        int retVal = container.open(url + fileName,
                IContainer.Type.WRITE, containerFormat_live);
        if (retVal < 0) {
            System.err.println("Could not open output container for live stream");
                    System.exit(1);
        }
        IStream stream = container.addNewStream(0);
        IStreamCoder coder = stream.getStreamCoder();
        ICodec codec =
                ICodec.findEncodingCodec(ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264);
        coder.setNumPicturesInGroupOfPictures(5);
        coder.setCodec(codec);
        coder.setBitRate(200000);
        coder.setPixelType(IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);
        coder.setHeight(height);
        coder.setWidth(width);
        System.out.println("[ENCODER] video size is " + width + "x" +
                height);
        coder.setFlag(IStreamCoder.Flags.FLAG_QSCALE, true);
        coder.setGlobalQuality(0);
        IRational frameRate = IRational.make(5, 1);
        coder.setFrameRate(frameRate);
        coder.setTimeBase(IRational.make(frameRate.getDenominator(),
                frameRate.getNumerator()));
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream is =
                XugglerRtmpReferenceImpl.class.getResourceAsStream("/libx264-normal.ffpreset");
        try {
            props.load(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("You need the libx264-normal.ffpreset file from the Xuggle distribution in your classpath.");
                    System.exit(1);
        }
        Configuration.configure(props, coder);
        coder.open();
        container.writeHeader();
        long firstTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lastTimeStamp = -1;
        int i = 0;
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            while (i < framesToEncode) {
                //long iterationStartTime = 
                System.currentTimeMillis();
                long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //grab the screenshot 
                BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new
                        Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
                //convert it for Xuggler 
                BufferedImage currentScreenshot = new
                        BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(),
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
                currentScreenshot.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0,
                        null);
                //start the encoding process 
                IPacket packet = IPacket.make();
                IConverter converter =
                        ConverterFactory.createConverter(currentScreenshot,
                                IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);
                long timeStamp = (now - firstTimeStamp) * 1000; //  convert to microseconds
                IVideoPicture outFrame =
                        converter.toPicture(currentScreenshot, timeStamp);
                if (i == 0) {
                    //make first frame keyframe 
                    outFrame.setKeyFrame(true);
                }
                outFrame.setQuality(0);
                coder.encodeVideo(packet, outFrame, 0);
                outFrame.delete();
                if (packet.isComplete()) {
                    container.writePacket(packet);
                    System.out.println("[ENCODER] writing packet of size " + packet.getSize() + " for elapsed time " + ((timeStamp -
                    lastTimeStamp) / 1000));
                    lastTimeStamp = timeStamp;
                }
                System.out.println("[ENCODER] encoded image " + i + " in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - now));
                        i++;
                try {
                    // sleep for framerate milliseconds 
                    Thread.sleep(Math.max((long) (1000 /
                            frameRate.getDouble()) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - now), 0));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Thread.sleep((long) (1000 / frameRate.getDouble())); 
            }
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        container.writeTrailer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is /libx264-normal.ffpreset?

Comment: Have you tried the way proposed here [FFmpeg-Presets](https://github.com/joeyblake/FFmpeg-Presets). You might also try the file included in version [xuggler-1.15.66.RC1](https://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/tags/xuggler-1.15.66.RC1/java/xuggle-xuggler/captive/ffmpeg/csrc/ffpresets/)